# Insert dom inside another dom as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I've been trying to find away of doing this:

```
stackUp = function(a){
    var stack = "";
    stack += "<div class='stackWrap'>";
    stack += "<div class='stackInfo'></div>";
    stack += "<div class='stackBox'>";
    stack += "</div>";
    stack += "</div>";
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){ $(stack).find("stackBox").append(a[i].box); }
    return $(stack);
}
```

all I want to do is to insert each box from a object into "stackBox" div remembered in "stack", can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you are using the wrong selector, to select by class use `.stackBox`, just `stackBox` tries to find an element named `stackBox`

Comment: Still the same thing, stack does not remember the html i have inside a[x].box

Comment: because you do not save the modification, see Arun's answer

Comment: can you tell me what is the value of a[i].box?

Comment: @Rahul:
`taskBox = function(t){var box;box = "<div data-id='"+t.id+"' class='coolwrapclass task'>";box+= "<div class='taskWrap'>";box+= "<div class='taskInnerWrap'>";box+= "<div class='taskTopwrap'>"; ... return $(box); }`

This is saved inside the object a[x].box

Answer (score 4):

In your loop, in every iteration you are creating a new jQuery object and is modifying it. But those changes will not get reflected in the string `stack`. And at the end you are creating a  new dom structure from the string `stack` and is returning it, so non of the changes in the loop is reflected in the returned object

```
stackUp = function (a) {
    var stack = "";
    stack += "<div class='stackWrap'>";
    stack += "<div class='stackInfo'></div>";
    stack += "<div class='stackBox'>";
    stack += "</div>";
    stack += "</div>";
    var $stack = $(stack);
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        $stack.find(".stackBox").append(a[i].box);
    }
    return $stack;
}
```

Comment: @AnoopJoshi missed the class selector, but the core issue is not that

Answer (score 1):

```
stackUp = function(a){
    var stackWrap = $("<div class='stackWrap'><div class='stackInfo'></div></div>")
    var stackBox = $("<div class='stackBox'></div>");

    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        stackBox.append(a[i].box);
    }

    stackWrap.append( stackBox );

    return stackWrap;
}
```